# Is https makes panel slower or lazy loading?

Tags: http, https

Previously I am using the http://domainname.com,

I got some security issue so the I moved to the https://domainname.com.

Previously the panel was loading very quickly after converted to https:// panel is very slow,

Is there any problem with the http and https.

Please give me some suggestion on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The size of each transaction over SSL has an additional overhead for encryption, however the real killer is latency.

For HTTP traffic, there has to be 2 complete round trips for each request. But over SSL, there's at least 4. Although bandwidth has increased massively in recent years, latency has not changed much. The only practical solution is to be closer to the server.